AndroidStudio: Execution failed for task ':app:checkLicenseAndroidMain'.?
I was programming along on my Android application in Android Studio (version Koala) and now I am suddenly getting build errors and I am stuck with:

Task :app:checkLicenseAndroidMain FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:checkLicenseAndroidMain'.
Header does not contain any of the required keywords: map(extension 'license' property 'keywords')

What has happened here? I recall that a few days before I had fiddled with some of the Java Lint options but I am not aware of (at least consciously) having changed anything re. licensing or license headers. And I had been building a couple of times in the days since.
Which option or what other setting could cause the above build error?
Can one at least find out which file causes the above? The error message does not give me any indication what and in which file I need to change to avoid the above build-stop. ||-(

Is it a project created by you, or an existing project from the Internet you modify and enhance?

It's a project I had created myself. But meanwhile I have found the reason for that error - see my answer below,

My bad. A month or so ago I had experimented with a license plugin ("org.cadixdev.licenser") but had commented it out again in my gradle file back then. Yesterday I must have accidentally uncommented it which caused the above error. I simply didn't have that on my radar any more...
